# Cumulative count in recoursetree?

Tags: django, django-mptt

Using [`django-mppt`](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) I want to browse my category hierarchy displaying the ammount of objects related to the current category in any of it's children.

Much like [`drill_down_for_node`](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/templates.html#examples) in the example shown, but only with the current node childrens...

The optimal would be

```
{% recursetree obj.get_children cumulative count model.Foreignkey.category in o_count%}
<li>
    <h2><a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}">{{ node }}</a></h2>
    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
    <ul class="children">
        <a href="{{ children.get_absolute_url }}">{{ children }} ({{o_count}})</a>
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Doesn't iterating over `get_children` and calling template tag on each one of them help?

Comment: I want a cumulative count of objects related to the children, as in "sum items in all descendent categories"...

Comment: @sunn0, not yet. Have the problem on standby at the moment. Will give it a new shot next week...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49431796/186202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a function for this on the TreeManager:

https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/managers.py#L250

Add the counts to the queryset in your view:

```
context['qs_with_related_count'] = model1.objects.add_related_count(
                                          obj.get_children(),
                                          model2, 
                                          'category',
                                          'o_count',
                                          True
                                   )
```

and in template:

```
{% recursetree qs_with_related_count %}
    <li>
        <h2><a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}">{{ node }} ({{ node.o_count }})</a></h2>
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
           <ul class="children">
               {{ children }}
           </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
 {% endrecursetree %}
```

Unfortunately I was trying to use a `ManyToManyField` as `rel_field`:

https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/90

but it looks like you are in luck ('category' not 'categories') :)

Comment: Haven't got time to try this. But it's probably correct. I'll accept the answer as there were no new ones. Thank you very much!